# Number of Edges in Sparse Graph?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I was reading Dijkstras Algorithm in Chap. 24 and got confused with meaning of sparse graph. They say "If the graph is sufficiently sparse—in particular,`E= o(V^2/lg V)`-we can
improve the algorithm by implementing the min-priority queue with a binary minheap."

My questions

1. From where they have derived the expression `E= o(V^2/lg V)`for sparse graph?
2. Can't we use min-priority queue in case of dense graph. What will be the affect of it on Dijkstra's time complexity?

Reference-CLRS Page-662 3rd Ed.

Please Read:

[image]

Comment: It seems that they derive the expression `E = o(V^2/lg V)` *right there in the link you provided*. Do you want explanations on this derivation, or did I misunderstand what is written there?

Comment: Also, regarding your question (2); the link you provide specifies the effect of it as `O((V+E)lg(V))`, doesn't it?

Comment: I suggest you edit the title and substitute No. by Number. No is another word, and the first time I read the question I was confused.

Comment: @anatolyg u mis-understood

Answer (score 2):

1. Substitute that expression for `E` into the total running time, `O((V + E)lg V)`, and you'll see that if `E=o(V^2/lg V)` the total will be `o(V^2)`, which is an improvement over the `O(V^2)` running time of not using a minheap.
2. Once again, substitute. Let's assume a complete graph, `E = V^2`. Then, the running time becomes `O((V + V^2)lg V) = O(V^2 lg V)`, which is worse than `O(V^2)`.